# crystal report crystal decision not found problem

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

This happened when I changed my laptop. The problem was i deleted and then added the references as they were showing error so it broke the build. I installed latest crystal report runtime from here https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

this the reference I got in the web.config which are there in the build . not changed

> 

```
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    <!--<add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>-->
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
  </assemblies>
```

Now it is giving some 840 errors like Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'CrystalReports' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Portal  C:\Users\MazharKaunain\OneDrive - Documents\MAZHAR WORKSPACE\Portal\Reports\ViewBooking.aspx.cs 10  Active

1. Crystal decisions need to be manually installed. they are not installed with the crystal report runtime ?
2. which version of  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine I need to install seeing the version in the web.config file

need to solve this problem. any suggestion to do it from start. or any other suggestion. I also don't want to break the build on the server

Comment: You might need to add reference to Crystal Reports Engine library. See the project file in text editor and see paths for all crystal reports libraries. You might need to update the path in the project file.

Comment: it finally succeeded but it is given error about not finding crystal.shared which is 13.0.3400.0 what I need to do

Comment: it is given runtime error

Comment: See if you could add reference to CrystalReports.Shared.dll assembly. Refer to this link-https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrystalReports.Shared/13.0.4000